# How to set "unsafe" Git LFS config items?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I want to set `lfs.activitytimeout` in LFS config, however doing this locally results in a warning:

> WARNING: These unsafe lfsconfig keys were ignored

How to I set `lfs.activitytimeout` for a repo?

**Edit:**
As per VonC's answer below, the real culprit is trying to set these values in the .lfsconfig file, not the vanilla .config file.  If you set them in the .config file they appear to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 2636](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2636), a `git config lfs.activitytimeout xx` seems the recommended approach, with the [default value being 30 seconds](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/48ffab044a182a24e515c4449b74b713cab1e2d5/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn#list-of-options)

Check your LFS version first.

A `git config -f .lfsconfig` though seems [limited to those values](https://github.com/Timmmm/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn#lfsconfig), as illustrated by [issue 4467](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4467) and [PR 4468](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/4468).

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah it's odd that you can set it in .config but not in .lfsconfig